# MacOS-like Password Popup

Tags: macos, popup, swift4

My team is working on an app that deals with a password. Right now it's able to do everything except give a MacOS-like popup when the entered password doesn't meet the criteria set. We have the data in a tooltip, and we know how to put it in an `NSAlert` message, but we'd like it to appear the same way the it does when a user changes their password within the OS. [Screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQAy6.png)
How do we do that? We're not using storyboards, so segues are out. Thanks!

Comment: The app we're building updates a user password, so we were able to tap into the OS's built-in logic to check the validity of the new password. We just want to make the interface as close to the native experience as possible, hence mimicking the password feedback window.

Comment: That's an `NSPopover` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspopover?language=objc)

Comment: @TheNextman Does that require the use of segues to work though? I had looked at that for another app and thought it did. Thanks!

Comment: No; you just assign a view controller as the `contentViewController` of the popover and then use `showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge:` to display it. The view controller can come from anywhere (storyboard, .xib, code).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/marteinn/d4842e3d404d6bac489c (Objective C, not Swift, but you get the idea)